# 4x4 keyboard matrix - why no pull down resistors?

Tags: switches, pulldown

I found many schematics out there for a 4x4 keyboard/switch matrix, both with and without diodes.

Yet I don't get it. If one doesn't add pull-down resistors, rows 1 to 4 will all be floating.

Can someone explain why pull down resistors they are not required in this case?

I plan to use an atmega32u4 microcontroller.

[image]

Comment: The direction flag on the column names should show inputs (point the other way), then it would probably be a little clearer. The rows need to be scanned one at a time to determine which switch is active in each row (set output, read each column, clear output).

Comment: thx Ron, but why active low instead of active high ? any reason for this ?

Comment: @user7082181 - Hi, Please don't be offended at polite suggestions. Your site profile doesn't indicate that you're not a native English speaker. The comment you replied to, linked to part of the site [help], in case you could follow those recommendations. Also there is a site [Code of Conduct](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/conduct) requiring everyone to be kind & respectful. Your comment was (understandably) flagged as unkind, so I have deleted it - as well as the comment you responded to, as it has served its purpose to inform you of that recommendation. So it's now a clean slate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way that you perform one scan of a keyboard like that goes like this:

- Pull row 1 low, all other rows high.  Read the column nibble.
- Pull row 2 low, all other rows high.  Read the column nibble.
- Pull row 3 low, all other rows high.  Read the column nibble.
- Pull row 4 low, all other rows high.  Read the column nibble.
- Combine the four nibbles into 16 key presses (a low bit = key pressed).

The rows are pulled low by the hardware external to the keyboard (in this case, by the microcontroller's GPIO).

Comment: And use some method to debounce. :)

Comment: WWWWhy wwwould I wwwwwant to do that?

Comment: You  might leave all four row drivers idling at logic "low". This allows the four column inputs to generate an **interrupt-on-change** when you hit any key. Then you proceed with Tim's scanning procedure, only allowing one-row-low at a time.

Answer (score 4):

Because the rows are outputs, resistors are not needed.

In fact, since AVR microcontrollers have inputs with internal pull-ups, the resistors on the columns are not needed either.

Comment: ok so we're talking open drains right ?

Comment: No, I wasn't, but now that you mentioned it, it does not matter if it is an open drain output or push pull output.

Comment: To be clear, the MCU row driver outputs can be push-pull because the keypad has key diodes. Without key diodes, you'd use open-drain drivers as multiple presses in a column will connect drivers together.